# JavaFX: how to get the color and alpha transparency of a pixel?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to get the pixel color / alpha transparency of a pixel of a JavaFX `Parent` or `Scene`?

For example, how do I get the pixel color of a `StackPane` at `(x,y)`?

In [Java Swing there is a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906929/java-swing-how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-of-a-jframe), `printAll`, from which the pixel can be extracted from any component.

However I can't find such a method in JavaFX.

EDIT: @kleopatra asked for a complete reproductive example, so here is it:

```java
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

How do I get the pixel color of `root`, say, at `x,y`?

Comment: You need to get the color and use [Color#getOpacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getOpacity--)

Comment: How do I get the color?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function to return the pixel color at any `x,y` coordinate of a `node`:

```java
static Color getColor(int x, int y, Node node) {
    SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
    sp.setTransform(new Translate(-x, -y));
    sp.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0,0,1,1));
    sp.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
    WritableImage image = node.snapshot(sp, null);
    return image.getPixelReader().getColor(0, 0);
}
```

It will also work if `Node` is replaced by `Scene`, as both classes share the method `snapshot`.